# Instagram Media/Search API

Tags: instagram-api

What is the smallest radius does Instagram Search Media API support ?

As I'm trying with radius of 50 meters, but not seems to be accurate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that some of the data returned from this API regardless of the radius are not accurate and not within the radius, there are some cases when 1 or 2 data points are way outside the radius, I manually filter out those, check out http://map.gramfeed.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think yes, the only way is doing manual filter over the result.

Comment: Do you know if there is any google map API Endpoint where you can check if a given point (Lat/Lng) falls within another address (Lat/Lng and Radius)?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry, The distance between two points is the length of the shortest path between them. This shortest path is called a geodesic. On a sphere all geodesics are segments of a great circle. To compute this distance, call computeDistanceBetween(), passing it two LatLng objects.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Is there server side API?